# Reactive Extensions crash .net process

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I'm starting using reactive extensions in my project and found the following problem. I have a subject inside my class and I need that all client observers process OnNext messages in different threads.

```
private Subject<IEnumerable<int>> _multiResponse =
    new Subject<IEnumerable<int>>();

public IObservable<IEnumerable<int>>> MultiResponse
{
     get
     {
         return _response.ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default);
     }
}
```

If the client throws exception in OnNext event all the process crashes because of unobserved exception in Task. StackTrace:

ProcessResponses(IEnumerable responses) in Scheduler.cs:line 149
   at System.Reactive.AnonymousSafeObserver'1.OnNext(T value)
   at System.Reactive.ScheduledObserver'1.Dispatch(ICancelable cancel)
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.b_*32(Action'1 a, ICancelable c)
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.TaskPoolScheduler.<>c*_DisplayClass7'1.b__6()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Is it an expected behavior or a bug in RX and what to do with it?

Comment: What is the type and message of the exception? Those are usually more important than the stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, paying attention now... this is about unobserved exceptions.

I think the fact that you are doing things asynchronously shouldn't matter. This synchronous code throws an `Exception`, as I would expect:

```
Observable.Return(1).Subscribe(
    _ => { throw new Exception(); });
```

However, I was hoping to find the following code *would* throw an `Exception` (thus explaining what you have seen) but at first I was very surprised to find that it does not!

```
Observable.Return(1).ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default).Subscribe(
    _ => { throw new Exception(); });
```

(EDIT - see below - this is .NET 4.5 behaviour)

Certainly switching to the `ThreadPoolScheduler` gives the expected `Exception`:

```
Observable.Return(1).ObserveOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance).Subscribe(
    _ => { throw new Exception(); });
```

EDIT:

Right - so I stopped being lazy and started reading the source code. It turns out the behaviour depends on whether you are on .NET 4.5 or not.

On .NET 4.5 the default behaviour of the task pool is NOT to let unobserved exceptions bring down the process. On .NET 4.0 it does. So Rx follows the platform default and behaves as per other schedulers on .NET 4.0 but silently swallows the exception on .NET 4.5.

So, assuming you are on .NET 4.0, what you are seeing is expected  - you have an unobserved exception.

Note also that because .NET 4.5 is an in place upgrade this is a breaking change. It's *what Framework is installed on the machine that counts,* **not** what Framework is selected in the project properties.

Source code that's relevant is here - worth a read, the comments are instructive:

http://rx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.PlatformServices/Reactive/Concurrency/TaskPoolScheduler.cs

Here are some comments on MSDN about this behaviour change (see the remarks), which also show how to impose .NET 4.0 behaviour on a .NET 4.5 installation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj160346(v=vs.110).aspx

My advice is to not rely on this behaviour but protect your OnNext ***handlers*** with exception handlers. To be clear, I mean Subscribers should not throw. The Rx Design guidelines are explicit that calls to OnNext, OnError and OnCompleted should NOT be protected. (See section 6.4 at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219)

Comment: I have been getting strange behaviours, code not running and sudden crashes without exception thrown. But when I use `ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)`it went away and everything works fine.
Should I use it everywhere now..?

Comment: @lolelo The fact that this "fixes" your problem is unsettling. I doubt the underlying problem is anything to do with Rx itself, and I would advise you to investigate further.

Comment: In xamarin, it turned out to be that I needed to invoke async on the main thread, synchronous would crash on older devices.. It might not have add anything to do reactive extensions

Comment: @Iolelo Good job, glad you found root cause!

Answer (score 0):

James World thanks for your help. I'm using .Net 4.0 and currently cannot move to 4.5.
In my task I need that

```
public IObservable<IEnumerable<int>>> MultiResponse
```

would always be available for subscribers. For this I've created the following extension method:

```
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<T> ObserveSafe<T>(this IObservable<T> observable, Action<Exception> onError)
    {
        var subject = new Subject<T>();

        observable.Subscribe(x =>
                             {
                                 try
                                 {
                                     subject.OnNext(x);
                                 }
                                 catch (Exception exception)
                                 {
                                     onError(exception);
                                 }
                             },
                             exception =>
                             {
                                 try
                                 {
                                     subject.OnError(exception);
                                 }
                                 catch (Exception ex)
                                 {
                                     onError(ex);
                                 }
                                 finally
                                 {
                                     subject.Dispose();
                                 }
                             },
                             () =>
                             {
                                 try
                                 {
                                     subject.OnCompleted();
                                 }
                                 catch (Exception ex)
                                 {
                                     onError(ex);
                                 }
                                 finally
                                 {
                                     subject.Dispose();
                                 }
                             });

        return subject;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not a big fan of this approach. Note that you are subscribing immediately here - even before a single downstream subscriber. The only reason I can think of to do this is because you don't own the observer code. As a slight improvement, consider refactoring to move the body of your method by moving it inside an Observable.Create (which only gets called on Subscribe). It would be better to handle exceptions in your Observers if you can. In general, you shouldn't be doing much in an Observer anyway; you don't want to be a slow consumer.

Comment: In general, there should be a one-one correspondence between calls to Subscribe to an Observable and calls to Subscribe to its upstream Observable, unless you are doing an explicit `Publish`. Also see sections 6.4 and 6.5 in design guidelines "Subscribe implementation should not throw" : http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219 That section might be useful to you. Note how it specifically advises NOT to protect calls to OnNext, OnError and OnCompleted.